# Why does .setAttribute not work when nested inside a function?

Tags: javascript, html, function, setattribute

I'll make it quick. I researched a lot but I'm not sure why this is not working.

I have a textarea tag which I want to set to 'data-something' tag using setAttribute("data-something","") command and it works just fine if I just list it out there. However what I'm doing is I"m creating a button that when clicked sets the attribute of the textarea to 'data-something', and no matter what it fails to operate when I nest setAttribute inside a myFunction and set button onclick="myFunction()". I'd appreciate if someone could explain a workaround that.

Thanks a ton for your patience.

This is what works:

```
<textarea></textarea>

<script>
textarea.setAttribute("data-something","")
</script>
```

This is what doesn't work

```
<textarea></textarea>

<button onclick="myFunction()"></button>

<script>
function myFunction(){
textarea.setAttribute("data-something","")
}
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say: it works fine if I just list it?

Comment: A function introduces its own "scope". Besides what you say works, doesn't work actually. That is `textarea` will be undefined in either case, unless you declare it and give it a value. In your case you need a `textarea` variable that points to the DOM element by reference, which you dont have.

Comment: @NubeColectiva I mean if I define the

 function myFunction(){
textarea.setAttribute("data-something","")
} and then list it in the script myFunction(), it would run just fine. But when I add an onclick event to it (like in the second example), it doesn't work.

Comment: But it doesn't "run just fine". `textarea` is undefined in both your examples. See JonoJames answer below on how to make it work.

Comment: You are not defining or selecting the textarea, I recommend doing it with document.getElementById('you-textarea-id');

Answer (score 1):

You have to give you element a handle getElementById then make the change

```js
function myFunction(){
  let textarea = document.getElementById("Foo");
  textarea.setAttribute("data-something","This is the set Data");
  console.log(textarea);
}
```

```html
<textarea id="Foo"></textarea>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Good explanation how an element name itself is not "global" to Javascript and thus the same name if used must be declared as a variable and the appropriate assignment (+1). The rest in your solution is self-explanatory.

Comment: Awesome glad i could help you could also do by tag name but that would mean you would have to work with an array of elements and that can get messy so by ID is the simplistic form eg. const cells = table.getElementsByTagName('td');

Comment: I'm not the OP but I was also thinking on lines of your last comment on how to handle multiple elements. I think your solution (above) is appropriate given what the OP actually presented.

Comment: @JonoJames hate to break the enthusiasm here but it seems like this isn't working either for some reason. I just repeated everything as you mentioned but like mentioned earlier, when I just call the function using myFunction() it works just fine, but when I do onclick="myFunction" it doesn't work at all. I can even post an image of my 10 line code if you want.

Comment: Try moving the <script> tag out  header and just before the </body> tag closes its probably not seeing the HTML DOM before trying to grab it. Remeber the Header is allways parsed first so if the JS is referring to element that are not drawn on the page yet therefore by moving the JS after the dom has been drawn you can render it